# How to prove $(\frac1\pi)\int_{-\pi}^\pi \left(\frac {1-r^2}{1-2r\cos\theta+r^2}\right)^2d\theta = \frac {2(1+r^2)}{1-r^2}$?

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-functions

So for this problem I need to use the fact that $\frac {1-r^2}{1-2r\cos\theta+r^2}$=$1+2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} r^n\cos n\theta$.

I replaced the term in the integral but i ended up getting $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} r^n+2$ as my final answer. Im not sure if I got it right and i need to reframe it to get $\frac {2(1+r^2)}{1-r^2}$ or my answer is completely wrong.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Do you mean $r^{n+2}?$

Comment: Geometric series?

Comment: This looks like you need to use Parseval's theorem at some point. If you have the integral of the magnitude of a function squared that should be the sum of the magnitude squared of the Fourier series coefficients (in the complex exponential, not real trig, basis)

Comment: You need to square the given fact (identity in question) and then integrate term by term. I have included this in my answer but you need to fill details.

Comment: Also the answer should be immediate from Parseval theorem as mentioned by @NinadMunshi. +1 for their comment.

Answer (score 3):

A much simpler way is to note that $$\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{dx}{a+b\cos x} =\frac{\pi} {\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}, a>|b|$$ and differentiate it with respect to $a$ to get $$\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{dx}{(a+b\cos x) ^2}=\frac{\pi a} {(a^2-b^2)^{3/2}}$$ Putting $a=1+r^2,b=-2r$ and noting that $$a^2-b^2=(1-r^2)^2$$ we can see that $$\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{dx}{(1-2r\cos x+r^2)^2}=\frac{\pi(1+r^2)}{(1-r^2)^3}$$ which is equivalent to your result in question.

The integral at the beginning of this answer is evaluated by using non-obvious substitution $$(a+b\cos x) (a-b\cos t) =a^2-b^2$$

---

Your own approach should lead to $$\int_{0}^{\pi}\left(\frac{1-r^2}{1-2r\cos x+r^2}\right)^2\,dx=\pi+4\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}r^{2n}\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos^2 nx\, dx$$ which equals $$\pi+2\pi\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}r^{2n}=\frac{\pi(1+r^2)}{1-r^2}$$ Note that while squaring you also get terms like $\cos mx\cos nx$ but their integral vanishes so I have ommitted these in the above calculation.

Also $x$ has been used in place of $\theta$ to reduce typing effort.

Answer (score 0):

You have reduced the problem to evaluating
$$
     \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left(1+2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}r^n\cos(n\theta)\right)^2d\theta.
$$
The terms $1,\cos(\theta),\cos(2\theta),\cdots$ are mutually orthogonal on $[-\pi,\pi]$, which further reduces the above to
$$
          \frac{1}{\pi}\left(\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}1d\theta+4\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}r^{2n}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos^2(n\theta)d\theta\right) \\
   = 2+\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}r^{2n}\pi \\
   =2+4r^{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(r^2)^n \\
   =2+4r^{2}\frac{1}{1-r^2} \\
   =2\frac{1+r^2}{1-r^2}.
$$
And that checks with your answer.